# Log of dependency does not show

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, slf4j, logback

I have a Play project, named FrontEnd, whose dependency is another project named Logic.

Inside the `build.sbt` file of the Logic project, I add slf4j and logback:

```
name := "Logic"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

seq(bintrayResolverSettings:_*)

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5"

libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2"
```

I also created a Logging trait inside the Logic project

```
package logic.logging

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

trait Logging {
  protected val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName().stripSuffix("$"))
}
```

Then, I included the Logic project inside the FrontEnd project:

```
name := "Frontend"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

lazy val logicProj = RootProject(file("../logic"))

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(logicProj)
```

Finally, in order to test the logging feature, I created a Global object inside FrontEnd

```
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api.Application
import play.api.Logger
import logic.logging.Logging

object Global extends GlobalSettings with Logging {
  override def onStart(app: Application) = {
    logger.info("Logic's logger: Application is started!!!")
    Logger.info("FrontEnd's logger: Application is started!!!")
  }
}
```

And the output on console is:

```
[info] application - FrontEnd's logger: Application is started!!!
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

In other words, the logger from logic.logging.Logging cannot log to the console. I wonder if anyone knows why and how to fix it.

PS: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28563376/1230453), it is possible that it has to do with the multiple bindings, i.e., the logback in Logic and in FrontEnd's Play library. However, I don't want to remove logback from Logic as the project itself is a standalone console application which needs to log the output to the console.

Edit: Even after removing `libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2"` from Logic's `build.sbt`, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find out that the log does not show as it is not "registered" to Play's logging configuration. It can be fixed by adding the following line into `configuration` tag of `application-logger.xml` file:

```
<logger name="logger" level="INFO" />
```

Then, I update the Logging object to include a logger prefix at all logger:

```
package logic.logging

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

trait Logging {
  protected val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("logger.%s".format(this.getClass().getSimpleName().stripSuffix("$")))
}
```

And it works as the output is:

```
[info] logger.Global - Logic's logger: Application is started!!!
[info] application - FrontEnd's logger: Application is started!!!
```